# Calibre custom news source - How to set publication author(s)

Tags: calibre

I have a few news downloads set up in Calibre (BBC, Guardian and a few custom ones as well).
I note that once they are downloaded that the 'Author(s)' column for the publication is set to 'calibre'.

Ideally, I would like this to reflect the actual publication, or, more generally, I'd like to be able to configure this myself. I have looked around in the docs, within the python script and generally on the net for answers but I can't see a way of doing this. I don't want to have to manually edit the metadata as this kind of defies the point of an automated download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was kind a hard nut to crack...
Regarding [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/1320600) this functionality is currently not available nor planned for the future.

In fact there is a workaround to more or less solve this issue. There is a real master tool called 'Metadata Plugboards' [hidden in the settings](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kindle_and_Calibre_Plugboards). This allows you to modify metadata when media is exported (save to disk, send per mail or upload to device etc. - this applies not when you simply convert to another format).

The tool gives you a lot of options - For this example I just chose `any format -> any device`. Then you can specify what should go to which metadata field. Select `authors` as target and enter the following template code

```
{authors:contains(calibre,{title},{authors})}
```

This replaces the author field with the title, if the author currently contains `calibre`, otherwise the authors field remains untouched.

More details on the template language are available at the [calibre manual](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/template_lang.html).

Comment: Splendid, thank you @Daniel. I was having problems with this but upgrading to 1.47 appeared to sort this out. 
I note that the changes are only reflected in the document once it gets sent rather than in Calibre but that isn't an issue. Thanks again.